# Use library that is saved via composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to run the following script:

```
<?php

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.symfony.com/blog/');

print($crawler);
```

My `composer.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
    "require": {
        "fabpot/goutte": "^3.2"
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Goutte\Client' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/src/t01-makeRequests.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/ubuntu/workspace/src/t01-makeRequests.php on line 5
```

Any suggestions, how to load the library correctly in my script?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thx for your reply! Should this be added to the composer.json?

Comment: No, to the top of the script. See [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) on autoloading.